# Why is my well pump sucking air?

Tags: plumbing, well

My pressure pump that goes to a bladder tank has a small hose. It was off and water leaked everywhere. I put it back on. After I turned  everything off and then turned water on in house.  After about 15 minutes it was sucking air again.

What's wrong? It's hard to check because my well is far from the house. Should I turn the pump off? I have a 500 gallon holding tank. Should I check for a new pump?

The pressure came back up in the bladder, then when that water was used there was no more water in house.

Comment: Oh yea the pressure tank is full.all full I tried to ck the air in it but tire gauge won't fit its a WellMate

Comment: I can't push down on the thing on top of pressure tank

Comment: If there is no air in the tank the well may start short cycling. One way to tell if the air charge is low or if the bladder is leaking is if you turn the water on and the well immediately starts the air charge is gone. A simple tire pump can be used to replace the air charge, if this happens again a new bladder may be needed. In some cases I have found it easier to replace the tank than the bladder, if the entire tank is replaced you will be good for years. Some bladders are a pain to install some are fairly easy and the bladders are reasonably priced, look into this as a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

That small black hose is probably an air purge line to insure that the pump from the storage tank to the wellmate tank vents air from that pump  in the event that the storage tank runs dry and the pump loads with air. What did you mean when you said that "in 15 minutes it was sucking air again"? The fitting on top of the wellmate tank is similar to the air valve on a car tire. You should be able to depress it with a small  screw driver or check the pressure with a tire gauge. Turn off the pump to the wellmate tank, run house water till it stops, then check the tanks pressure. It should have a pressure that is slightly less than where the pump turn on. If not it needs to be pressurized or the bladder may be bad. At this point you may be better off calling a well guy or someone that understands water well systems.